# Kube ingress and elb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, kubernetes, ingress

I am running my (kops) kube cluster on AWS. The cluster is in the private subnet. I am not able to create an external (internet facing) load balancer because my cluster is in private space. Is there any way that I can create an internet facing load balancer with my cluster sitting in the private space, if that is not a possible solution how do I expose my service running inside my kube to the outside world?

I am creating with the below annotation for my service

```
    kind: Service
    metadata:
    name: helloweb
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
```

If I don't use "-internal" in the annotation the service goes to pending state

```
     Normal   EnsuringLoadBalancer        9s (x3 over 24s)  service- 
     controller  Ensuring load balancer
     Warning  CreatingLoadBalancerFailed  8s (x3 over 24s)  service- 
     controller  Error creating load balancer (will retry): failed to 
     ensure load balancer for service default/helloweb: could not find 
     any suitable subnets for creating the ELB
```

I have also tried ingress, even ingress is not able to create an external elb. Here's my ingress defenition...

```
    kind: Service
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
    name: ingress-nginx
    namespace: ingress-nginx
    labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0


    kubectl get ing
    NAME        HOSTS                 ADDRESS   PORTS AGE                                         
    ingress-rules exampleapp1.kubexpress.cloud,exampleapp2.kubexpress.cloud   internal- 
      l0adbalancer.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com   80        10d
```

Comment: Amazon load balancers (public facing) support instances in private subnets. Are your VPC and subnets configured correctly?

Comment: Yes, they are configured correctly.

Comment: I think theya re configured properly, are there any specific things you want me to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my Kops configurtion. I corrected it by creating utility subnet for each private subnet where my kube master/worker nodes will be at.